# Adding value only to a first combination during merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two `dfs`:

`df_1`

```
date            id          value
2021-01-01      A1          100
2021-01-01      A1          200
2021-01-01      A1          300
2021-01-02      A1          100
2021-01-02      A1          200
2021-01-03      A1          500
2021-01-03      A1          800
```

`df_2`

```
date            id          value_to_add
2021-01-01      A1          150 
2021-01-03      A1          350
```

I am trying to maintain the structure of `df_1` and to add the `value_to_add` in the first occurrence during merge so that the end result would look like this after filling `NaN` and all but the first values with a `0`:

```
date            id          value       value_to_add
2021-01-01      A1          100         150 
2021-01-01      A1          200         0               # 0 because the 150 have been already added
2021-01-01      A1          300         0
2021-01-02      A1          100         0               # 0 because value_to_add does not exist
2021-01-02      A1          200         0
2021-01-03      A1          500         350 
2021-01-03      A1          800         0               # 0 because the 350 have been already added
```

My first thought was to drop duplicates of a `['date', 'id']` subset, then merge `df_2` to it but then I am not sure how I would go back to the original structure of `df_1`.

So the problem is the following - *being able to merge on the first occurrence of keys during `pd.merge` operation*. I was not able to find anything on this topic and frankly not sure how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter duplicated values by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with invert mask and [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) for avoid remove new columns added from `merge`:

```
df_1.loc[~df_1.duplicated(['date', 'id']),
         df_1.columns.union(df_2.columns)] = df_1.merge(df_2, how='left')
df_1 = df_1.fillna(0)
print (df_1)
         date  id  value  value_to_add
0  2021-01-01  A1    100         150.0
1  2021-01-01  A1    200           0.0
2  2021-01-01  A1    300           0.0
3  2021-01-02  A1    100           0.0
4  2021-01-02  A1    200           0.0
5  2021-01-03  A1    500         350.0
6  2021-01-03  A1    800           0.0
```

Another idea with helper counter column:

```
df_1 = df_1.assign(g = df_1.groupby(['date', 'id']).cumcount()).merge(df_2.assign(g=0), how='left')
df_1 = df_1.drop('g', 1).fillna(0)
print (df_1)
         date  id  value  value_to_add
0  2021-01-01  A1    100         150.0
1  2021-01-01  A1    200           0.0
2  2021-01-01  A1    300           0.0
3  2021-01-02  A1    100           0.0
4  2021-01-02  A1    200           0.0
5  2021-01-03  A1    500         350.0
6  2021-01-03  A1    800           0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s =df_1.set_index(['date','id']).join(df_2.set_index(['date','id']))

s=s.assign(value_to_add=np.where(~s['value_to_add'].duplicated(keep='first'),s['value_to_add'],np.nan)).fillna(0)
```